# Does java.nio.file.Files.copy call sync() on the file system?

Tags: java, file, synchronization, filesystems, nio

i'm developing an application that has to reboot the system after a file has been uploaded and verified. The file system is on an sd card, so it must be synced to be sure the uploaded file has actually been saved on the device.

I was wondering if java.io.file.Files.copy does the sync or not.

My code runs like this:

```
public int save(MultipartFile multipart) throws IOException {

    Files.copy(multipart.getInputStream(), file, standardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    if (validate(file)) {
        sync(file); <-- is it useless?
        reboot();
        return 0;
    } else {
        Files.delete(file);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I tried to find a way to call sync on the fs in the nio package, but the only solution that i've found is:

```
public void sync(Path file) {
    final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.toFile());
    final FileDescriptor fd = fos.getFD();
    fd.sync();
}
```

which relies on old java.io.File .

Comment: The OS should sync on a reboot. Calling sync explicitly is unlikely to make it more synced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `Files.copy(...)`, you will see that it doesn't perform a `sync()`. In the end, it will perform a copy of an input stream into an output stream corresponding to the first 2 arguments passed to `Files.copy(...)`.

Furthermore, the `FileDescriptor` is tied to the stream from which it is obtained. If you don't perform any I/O operation with this stream, other than creating a file with `new FileOutputStream(...)`, there will be nothing to `sync()` with the fie system, as is the case with the code you shared.

Thus, the only way I see to accomplish your goal is to "revert" to the old-fashioned `java.io` API and implement a stream-to-stream copy yourself. This will allow you to `sync()` on the file descriptor obtained from the same `FileOutputStream` that is used for the `copy` operation.

Comment: Thank you Lolo, i'll do as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'll say the copy operation is depending on your OS JRE code, so if you want to be sure of the file Copy at OS level, continue to explicitly call the sync() method.

Answer (score 0):

This was because `SYNC` and `DSYNC` were annoyingly omitted from `StandardCopyOption` enum, yet were provided in `StandardOpenOption` enum for file targets, so you need to use `FileChannel` and `SeekableByteChannel` if supported by `FileSystemProvider`, like :

```
Set<? extends OpenOption> TARGET_OPEN_OPTIONS = EnumSet.of(StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
FileChannel.out = target.getFileSystem().provider().newFileChannel(target, TARGET_OPEN_OPTIONS);
SeekableByteChannel = Files.newByteChannel(source, StandardOpenOption.READ);
out.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
out.force(boolean metadata); // false == DSYNC, true == SYNC
```

Using java.io.FileOutputStream.getFD().sync() is an obsolete "solution", because you lose all support for NIO2 `FileSystems`, like the often bundled `ZipFileSystem`, and it can still fail if not supported by the native class implementations or OS!

Using DSYNC or SYNC when opening an OutputStream via a FileSystemProvider is another option, but may cause premature flushing of a FileSystem cache.